# spacemacs - How do I open from the recent file list?

Tags: spacemacs, recentf

I see the recent files listed when I boot up `emacsclient -nc`. How do I open them in the current window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To go to the recent files list, you can press `r` in the `*spacemacs*` buffer. Then you can use `j` or `k` (if you've got vim-style editing) to navigate up and down the list. Press `<RET>` to open a file.